# How to float number while fetching data as json in jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

My question is about to float number in jquery. I looked other questions about it in this site but I couldn't find which I look.

In part of my code, I used `$.post` in jquery. I send request to database and fetch data as `json` format. In my database, some numbers' format is  like 345,54565000000. So, I want to float numbers 5 digit after comma.

Part of my code is :

```
$.post("http://localhost/ajax.php",
      function(data) {
          var listdata;
          $.each(data, function(i,item){

              listdata += "<td>"+item.number+"</td>";

          });

            $(".result).empty().html(listdata);

    },"json"
);
```

Some of my trials are like:(which is not worked)

1.)

```
var number = (item.number).toFixed(5);
listdata += "<td>"+number+"</td>";
```

2.)

```
var number=item.number;
var new_number = number.toFixed(5);
listdata += "<td>"+new_number+"</td>";
```

Thank you for your replies.

Comment: `number = number.toString().split("."); number[1].=substr(0, 5); number = (number[0] + "" + number[1]);`

Comment: are you using a comma or a period? Rather, do you want the output as a comma or as a decimal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var number = 345.54565000000​;

var parsedNumber = parseFloat(parseInt(number*100000,10)/100000);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ASwjf/);

If that seperator is in fact a comma, you'll have to replace it with `.replace(',', '.')`

Answer (score 1):

I use this function:

```
function roundNumber(number,decimals) {
    var newString;// The new rounded number
    decimals = Number(decimals);
    if (decimals < 1) {
        newString = (Math.round(number)).toString();
    } else {
        var numString = number.toString();
        if (numString.lastIndexOf(".") == -1) {// If there is no decimal point
            numString += ".";// give it one at the end
        }
        var cutoff = numString.lastIndexOf(".") + decimals;// The point at which to truncate the number
        var d1 = Number(numString.substring(cutoff,cutoff+1));// The value of the last decimal place that we'll end up with
        var d2 = Number(numString.substring(cutoff+1,cutoff+2));// The next decimal, after the last one we want
        if (d2 >= 5) {// Do we need to round up at all? If not, the string will just be truncated
            if (d1 == 9 && cutoff > 0) {// If the last digit is 9, find a new cutoff point
                while (cutoff > 0 && (d1 == 9 || isNaN(d1))) {
                    if (d1 != ".") {
                        cutoff -= 1;
                        d1 = Number(numString.substring(cutoff,cutoff+1));
                    } else {
                        cutoff -= 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            d1 += 1;
        } 
        newString = numString.substring(0,cutoff) + d1.toString();
    }
    if (newString.lastIndexOf(".") == -1) {// Do this again, to the new string
        newString += ".";
    }
    var decs = (newString.substring(newString.lastIndexOf(".")+1)).length;
    for(var i=0;i<decimals-decs;i++) newString += "0";
    return newString;
}
```

So in your code, change line 6 to:

```
listdata += "<td>"+ roundNumber(item.number, 5) +"</td>";
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It works; but without this huge function, other replies does work. Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have commas, and you want to stick with commas, so that will break any Float related functions, so... quick and dirty, but does the job:

**Replace**

```
listdata += "<td>"+item.number+"</td>";
```

**With**

```
listdata += "<td>"+parseFloat(item.number.replace(',', '.')).toFixed(5).replace('.', ',')+"</td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

the fasted way I've found is

```
((number * Math.pow(10, numberOfDigits)) | 0) / Math.pow(10, numberOfDigits)
```

EDIT: forgot the Math.pow, that's important.